# Extract all text before \n in R regex

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract all text in a string before a "\n" appears.

Test string:

```r
string <- "Stack Overflow\nIs a great website for asking programming questions\nOther Info"
```

Solution extracts "Stack Overflow"

Bonus point if it grabs the first word of the string and the last word before the "\n"
Example:

```r
string2 <- "Stack Overflow Dot Com\nIS a great website for asking programming questions\nOther Info"
```

Solution extracts "Stack Com"

Comment: `strsplit(string, split = "\\n")` probably the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to have a solution with regexp, to answer your first question

```
/(.*)/
```

will match the whole string before your first end of line (\n)
[regexp101 Test](https://regex101.com/r/HGavtH/1)

To have the first and the last word matched on a one liner you can try

```
/([^ ]+).* (.*)$/
```

Probably someone can improve my answer to filter out this solution to match the first and last word before the first occurrence of newline.
[regexp101 Test](https://regex101.com/r/SZFSjk/1)

Answer (score 0):

Regexp for first example [click](https://regex101.com/r/gbilgo/1)

```
^(?:([\w\s]+)\\n)
```

Regexp for second example [click](https://regex101.com/r/p6lB2h/1)

```
^(?:(\w*\w\b)[\w\s]+\s(\w*\w\b)\\n)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is trick of using double `gsub`

```
> s
[1] "Stack Overflow\nIs a great website for asking programming questions\nOther Info"
[2] "Stack Overflow Dot Com\nIS a great website for asking programming questions\nOther Info"

> gsub("\\s.*\\s", " ", gsub("\n.*", "", s))
[1] "Stack Overflow" "Stack Com"
```